# Best way to store webshop item data as a snapshot when an order is created?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, data-integrity

I'm designing the architecture of my application and I'm running into an issue. For the webshop every `Order` entity has a relationship with a `Store` and many `StoreItem`'s. This allows for quick fetching of information when a user wants to view the `Order`.

However, when a `StoreItem` is altered, or even worse, deleted, this information is no longer relevant/available when looking at the `Order` entity. I have two possible solutions for this, and I would like your feedback on them:

1. When an `Order` is created, copy the `Store` and `StoreItem` into `OrderStore` and `OrderStoreItem` entities that will never be changed, even if the original entities are altered or removed. The `Order` will now automatically reference to the `OrderStore` and `OrderStoreItem` entities.
2. When an `Order` is created, copy all necessary data as JSON into special fields in the `Order` entity. Every time data is requested, get the JSON and turn it into data the system can use.

Which of the two options is the better one? I'm drawn to number 1, as that keeps the data relational and easily accessible throughout the application.

If you know of a better way to do this, feel free to add it. I'm trying to keep everything relational, so no child objects/tables.

Comment: Option1 is what I'd go with.  An order is a snapshot in time, and everything having to do with the order, including customer information, should be saved as history somewhere in the database.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Why should I save customer information per order as well? Is that in case I need the data someday or is it somehow used in the admin panel of a webshop / e-commerce application?

Comment: Because people move, change phone numbers, change email accounts.  Depending on your location, It can make a legal difference if you don't have the customer information as it existed when the customer made an order.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That makes sense. As my users have a lot of data, I will go with option 1 and think of a efficient way of saving the user data snapshots. Thanks a lot!